Compute $\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}\ dx$
Let's consider
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}\ dx$$
First, I note that
$$\frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}=\frac{1}{e^{-x}(e^{2x}+e^{x}+1)}=\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^x+1}$$
So, I can rewrite the integral as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}\ dx=\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1}\ dx$$
I use the following substitution:
$$t=e^x \Longrightarrow dt=e^x dx$$
and then
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+e^{x}+1}\ dx=\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{t^2+t+1}\ dt=\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\ dt=$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\ dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}}_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$
But, observing that $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}<1$, I have to put a minus sign to the result, therefore, I get:
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}\ dx=-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$
Is it correct? Is there a faster way to solve it?

This seems fast enough already

For $\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\ dt$, you could use $u=t+\frac12$ and $\int\dfrac{du}{u^2+a^2}=\dfrac1a\arctan(\dfrac ua)$

By the way, I found the limits of the original integral to be strange. As $0<\frac{\sqrt3-1}2<1$ and $\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}2\right)<0$. Which means the integral is taken over zero to a negative number and not the vice versa.

Yes, that's true, but it's probably done on purpose to make people realize that the extremes of integration need to be switched.

Your final answer is right, but your approach is wrong. You miscalculate an $\arctan$ argument, get an answer exactly $-1$ times the right one, then fudge it.

Yes, I noticed it as suggested in the answers below, thanks!

Note that the substitution $e^x= \frac{1-\sqrt3 t}{1+\sqrt3t}$ simplifies the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}dx
=-\frac2{\sqrt3}\int_0^{\tan \frac\pi{12}}\frac1{1+t^2}dt=-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}
$$

Uh, ok but where do I get this equation from? Does it follow from some notable identity or is it just very ingenious?

It can be identified using the fact that there is $\cosh x$ in the denominator and the tangent half-angle substitution.

@SigmaAlgebra See also this post; you can break down this substitution into steps of applying $x\to\log x$, then $x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, and finally $x\to\sqrt3,x$.

You can't just "put a minus sign". It's good that you recognize that $a = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2} < 1$, and its consquence: the upper limit is less than the lower limit and since $f(x) = \bigl(e^{x}+1+e^{-x}\bigr)^{-1}$ is positive, the value of the definite integral must be negative. Note: $\ln a \approx -1.005$, so it looks like $-1$ but it's not quite!

But, you've made a mistake: $\arctan(\sqrt{3}\,) = \tfrac{\pi}{3}$, so the value of the integral is
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \biggl( \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{3} \biggr) 
= - \frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}} 
= - \frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{18} 
\approx -0.3023
$$
By a happy (unhappy?) coincidence,
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{3} = -\frac{\pi}{12}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{12}, 
$$
which is why your (incorrect) answer was only off by a sign.

You're right, so it comes out negative and I don't have to change the sign otherwise I would calculate the integral "in the opposite direction" let's say?

Yes, the following equation is always true whenever either integral (and hence the other) converges:
$$
\int_a^b f(x),\mathrm{d}x + \int_b^a f(x),\mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$

Yess, got it! Thank you very much.

Your answer is correct, but you have made $2$ mistakes in the last few steps:

$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\ dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}}_1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$
But, observing that $\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}<1,\text{ I have to put a minus sign to the result}}$, therefore, I get:
$$\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}\ dx=-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$

Note that $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{3}=\frac{\pi}3$ and you have to plug in the values of $t$ from the limits in the same order as they are written. This is the statement of the $2^{nd}$ part of the FTC):
$$\int_a^bf'(x)\mathrm dx=f(b)-f(a)$$
Alternative method:
Let
$$\mathcal I=\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{\mathrm dx}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}\right)} \frac{\mathbb dx}{2\cosh x+1}$$
This can be solved by the tangent half-angle substitution:
$$t=\tanh\left(\frac{x}2\right)\implies\mathrm dx=\frac{2\mathrm dt}{1-t^2}, \cosh x=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}$$
$$\implies\mathcal I=2\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt3-3}{\sqrt3+1}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{3+t^2}$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt3}\right)\right]_0^{\frac{\sqrt3-3}{\sqrt3+1}}$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=-\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt3+1}\right)$$
$$\implies \mathcal I=\boxed{-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}}$$

Very nice strategy!

Here is another way to solve the integral that involves hyperbolic functions.
Recall that $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$
Immediately we see:
$$\int\frac{dx}{e^x+e^{-x}+1}=\int\frac{dx}{2\cosh(x)+1}$$
Using the substitution $u=\frac{\tanh(\frac x2)}{\sqrt3}$ we're left with the integrand $\frac{1}{u^2+1}$ which of course is $\arctan(u)$. Remember to change the bounds, and after computing we get $-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}$

(Yes, I later found another answer saying the same thing. But I think it good to tell the OP twice lest (s)he miss it.)
You made a slight error. I highlight where the problem is with red coloration:
$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\ dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}}_1\color{red}{=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$
When you substituted values for $t$, you got $(2/\sqrt3)\arctan(1)$ at the upper boundary and $(2/\sqrt3)\arctan(\sqrt3)$ at the lower boundary, then apparently rendered $\arctan(1)=\pi/4$ and $\arctan(3/\sqrt3)=\arctan(\sqrt3)=\pi/6$. But, in fact, $\arctan(\sqrt3)=\pi/3$. With the proper substitution of values, you get the negative sign without having to "fudge" it in:
$$=\frac{4}{3}\int_{1}^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}\ dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{2t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]^{\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}}_1\color{blue}{=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}=-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$
